# How to set fix x-Axis & y-Axis in highCharts Barchart for swift

Tags: ios, swift, highcharts

I use Highcharts in my ios app.
I make horizontal column chart with 2 y-Axis (top & bottom)
I want to set static xAxis & yAxis value. How can i set?
I want to below static values :

xAxis :[text1,text2,text3,text4,text5]

yAxis (at top) : [0,200,400,600,800,1000]

yAxis (at bottom) : [text1,text2,text3,text4]

Have try with setting min & max value but not get the result.
I am not able to set String value for yAxis at bottom

Pls suggest.

Comment: Hi @Reena, You can use a combination of category and linear axis type with defined `min`, `max` and `tickPositions` properties. Please check the idea in JS: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cxu852ey/

Comment: Thanks it solved my issue